# substring string by ant

Tags: ant

Could somebody help me.I would like to get substring of string by ant.For example I have path **d:\Folder_for_Ant\Incremental_Build\My.ear\Common\classes.jar** I would to get word **"Common"** by substring this path.How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html).

Or you could use scripting ([scriptdef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html)) where you could use javacript